# How does visual web WYSIWYG editor works?

Tags: editor, rich-text-editor, optimizely

I've seen some editors doing the same as Dreamweaver but on the Internet, how is that done is what I'd like to know. What technologies are involved?

Exemples: visualwebsiteoptimizer.com and optimizely.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Optimizely & Visual Website Optimizer handle visual DOM editing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224756/how-does-optimizely-visual-website-optimizer-handle-visual-dom-editing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mainly javascript

Comment: More details here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224756/how-does-optimizely-visual-website-optimizer-handle-visual-dom-editing